# WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have multiple files in multiple directories. All of these files have the same name, and I want to combine those files with the same name as one file, in another directory.

```
import os
import glob   

filenames = [glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'C:', 'Users' , 'Vishnu' ,'Desktop','Test_folder','Input','*.txt')), glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'C:', 'Users' , 'Vishnu' , 'Desktop','Test_folder','Output','*.txt'))]    
filenames[0].extend(filenames[1])
filenames=filenames[0]

if( not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'C:', 'Users' , 'Vishnu' , 'Desktop' ,'Test_folder', 'Test_output'))):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'C:', 'Users' , 'Vishnu' , 'Desktop' ,'Test_folder', 'Test_output'))
for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname) as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            f = open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'C:', 'Users' , 'Vishnu' , 'Desktop' ,'Test_folder', 'Test_output','{:}.txt'.format(os.path.split(fname)[-1] )), 'a+')
        f.write(line)
        f.close()    #This should take care of the permissions issue
```

But Getting Error:

```
os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'Test_output'))
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\HOME\\Desktop\\Test_output'
>>>
```

***Edited Code***

```
import os
import glob  

filenames = [glob.glob(os.path.join('C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Test_folder/Input/','*.txt')), glob.glob(os.path.join('C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Test_folder/Output/','*.txt'))]    

for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname).readlines() as all_lines:
        for line in all_lines:
            f = open(r'C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Test_output/{:}'.format(str(fname.split('/')[-1]), 'a')   
            f.write('{:}\n'.format(line)
            f.close()
```

Error:

```
f.write('{:}\n'.format(line)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It pretty much says that the directory "Desktop" does not exist.

Comment: @table, But I have all file in the respective folder on "Desktop". I am not understand what are you trying to say?

Comment: `C:\\HOME` does not exist... Why are you expanding the tilde if you enter the full path?

Comment: Are you sure, that the `C:\Home\Desktop` is what you are going for? Cause in the code you are trying to use directory 'C:\Users\Vishnu\Desktop`

Comment: @table, My Input dir: `C:\Users\Vishnu\Desktop\Test_folder\Input ` and `C:\Users\Vishnu\Desktop\Test_folder\Output` . Final output: `C:\Users\Vishnu\Desktop\Test_folder\Test_output`

Comment: Nesting function calls like you have done in your `mkdir` might look clever, but it is a pig to debug.  Split that statement into three components, assign temporary variables to the result of `os.path.expanduser` and (most important) `os.path.join` and `print` each one.  You can always glue them back together when you have the code working.  Nesting function calls is just making your job unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: @cdarke, Dear, I am new in puthym, can you please explain ?

Comment: The syntax error is because you omitted a close bracket `)` on the `format` statement (the line above where the error was reported).  But why are you doing the `str()` anyway?  Again, using nested function calls makes debugging more difficult, especially when you are a beginner.

Comment: @cdarke, Can you suggest any other way how to combine two folder's data in another folder?. I have multiple files in multiple directories. All of these files have the same name, and I want to combine those files with the same name as one file, in another directory.

Comment: You mean you wish to concatenate the files?  That's quite simple.  How large are the files?

Comment: @cdarke, I have seven folder as input files and I want to combine all file data in one final output file in another directory. In one folder I have 1000 files in each folder same name file in all input folders. Please let me know simple way?

Comment: @cdarke, can you please help me to fix error?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `os.makedirs()` to make sure that every directory along your path will be created(if it's not exist already).

Answer (score 1):

Some part of your path doesn't exist. You're using `C:\HOME` which is not the same as `C:\User\HOME`.

[`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) says the following in the documentation.

> On Windows, HOME and USERPROFILE will be used if set, otherwise a combination of HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE will be used. An initial ~user is handled by stripping the last directory component from the created user path derived above.

So it seems that only the username is being expanded, not the entire user home path.

Answer (score 0):

I have to get this right, you explanation is not clear to me - I know it must be difficult if English is not your first language.  This is the way I see it, please let me know if I am describing your problem correctly.

You have several folders, I'm going to call them `folder1` and `folder2`.  Within those folders you have files with the same name, for example `folder1\file1.txt` and `folder2\file1.txt`.  These are to be concatenated (joined) into a third folder, `folder3\file1.txt`.

```
import glob
import os.path

# Alter these to match your folder names
folder1 = 'folder1'
folder2 = 'folder2'
folder3 = 'folder3'

if not os.path.isdir(folder3): 
    os.mkdir(folder3)
    print(folder3, "created")

for fname1 in glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder1, '*.txt')):
    basen = os.path.basename(fname1)
    fname2 = os.path.join(folder2, basen)
    if os.path.isfile(fname2):
        outfname = os.path.join(folder3, basen)
        with open(outfname, 'wb') as outf: 
            with open(fname1, 'rb') as f1:
                outf.write(f1.read())
            with open(fname2, 'rb') as f2:
                outf.write(f2.read())
```

Please let me know if this is NOT what you need.